# Is it safe to parallel a 2 A breaker with a 10 A breaker in a testing situation?

Tags: safety, testing

I need a testing rig when repairing mains appliances.

My initial idea is a DIN rail system with one receptacle and two breakers: one 2 A one for low power stuff and a 10 A one for some high power stuff like microwaves and vacuums and such.

The two breakers would be connected in parallel with only the 2 A breaker active normally and the 10 A would be "switched on" when a higher tripping current is required.

Is this a safe way to do this? I also though about putting a 16 A breaker in front of both for redundancy (all of these are below the house breaker and wiring rating).

Comment: What do you think the advantage of having a 2A breaker instead of a 10A would be?

Comment: If both breakers are connected in parallel only one of them should be switched on. If you test low power stuff only the 2 A breaker and for high power stuff only the 10 A stuff.

Comment: Sounds medium-illegal. But I see your point. For a finished CE product, it is not allowed to require a 2 A breaker, but for testing it may have a purpose.

Comment: The 2A breaker is there just for the low power stuff (50W or less) which I think 10A is a little too much. Basically if there's a short or a fault in the device I want the breakers in the test rig to trip before the house breaker, so I don't interfere with my family's stuff, as we're all on one receptacle breaker (I know, it's bad, but it's an old house, so nothing I can do about it).  I also don't plan on making any products with it, it's just strictly for testing purposes, so that I'm not breaking any regulations.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the 2A breaker will trip first. All you're protecting against is a rather obscure fault that causes a device to take more than 2A but less than 10A.

Comment: The 10A breaker would be active only when the appliance is high powered and the 2A wouldn't be enough. At that point I'm ok with the 2A breaker tripping (in fact I'd switch it off manually) and I want it tripping at only 10A or more. I'm only asking if it would somehow affect the current sensing making the 10A trip at like 5A or something.

Comment: What about using a changeover switch to manually switch between them rather than using the 10A breaker? Something like https://mastertrade.co.uk/hg-sft225-hager-sft225-switch-changeover-dp-25a.html ?

Comment: Using a changeover switch was the second option. It's just a little too expensive, so I wanted to look for some other possible ways to do it.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @GameFan there's also no guarantee that the 2A breaker would trip before the 16A breaker in your home panel. You'd need to look at the trip curves for both.

Comment: I thought that if the breakers are both a B characteristic and one is rated lower, than the lower rating would trip faster. Am I wrong on that?

Comment: If you have a 2A breaker in series with a 16A one, and you then have a short-circuit causing (for example) 100A to flow, then you should expect *both* breakers to trip, because they've both exceeded the 'instantaneous' magnetic-trip threshold. There's no mechanism to make the smaller breaker trip faster than the larger one in that case. You'd only expect the smaller one to trip faster in the thermal part of the trip curve or if the current exceeds the rating of the smaller breaker but doesn't exceed that of the larger one. Remember that a breaker does not limit the instantaneous fault current.

Comment: In a short circuit situation the breakers take a finite time to trip simply due to the mechanicals. So it is very possible the upstream breakers may trip as well. For more moderate overloads, the situation is a bit more predictable. Remember the fuse (circuit breaker etc) is to protect the wiring, not the load. If you want a ‘soft’ start you can put an incandescent lamp in series. This is a common technique when fixing switched mode supplies as the lamp will allow enough current for the psu to start up and limit the current in case it fails hopefully avoiding the semiconductors exploding.

Comment: @Kartman Is there a way I can limit the current like with the incandescent lamp above the 40-100W that an incandescent lamp is rated for? The lamp solves the low power stuff, now I need something like that for 800W+ loads (for the occasional microwave or large motor that comes my way). I can't think of anything drawing that much outside of a large heater, but that would make it impractical.

Comment: why not have two receptacles and two breakers? You could also use an old skool hot wire fuse for the low power one, you know the let-through and breaking curve for that type.

Comment: @Neil_UK I thought about having two receptacles, but I didn't want to have to unplug/replug all the time. Better to just have one and have a switch that you just flip. It's an option, but having one receptacle is just a convenience thing. Also: You mean glass/ceramic fuses right? I want something I can just reset and not have to replace.

Comment: @GameFan either a glass/ceramic cartridge, or a rewireable fuse that's cheap and easy to replace. Then you can use exactly the gauge of tinned copper wire for your desired carrying/breaking characteristics.